# Showing two graphs isomorphic using their adjacency matrices

Tags: graph-theory

I don't know how to solve the following problem:

> Show that two simple graphs $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic if and only if there exists a permutation matrix $P$ such that $A_G=PA_HP^t$.

Here $A$ is the adjacency matrix. I have a feeling this shouldn't be very difficult, but my linear algebra is not very good, am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Multiplying by $P$ on the left permutes the rows of the matrix. Multiplying by $P^t$ on the right permutes the columns. The important thing here is that the two permutations are the same if you think of them as acting on indices. There is hardly any linear algebra needed, just chasing definitions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here’s an example that may get you thinking in the right direction. Consider $PAP^t$, where $P$ is the permutation matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&1\\
1&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&1&0&0
\end{bmatrix}$$

and, as an illustrative example,

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&3&4\\
2&3&4&5\\
0&1&2&3\\
3&2&1&0
\end{bmatrix}\;.$$

We have

$$PA=\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&1\\
1&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&1&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&3&4\\
2&3&4&5\\
0&1&2&3\\
3&2&1&0
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
3&2&1&0\\
1&2&3&4\\
0&1&2&3\\
2&3&4&5
\end{bmatrix}\;,
$$

and then

$$
PAP^t=\begin{bmatrix}
3&2&1&0\\
1&2&3&4\\
0&1&2&3\\
2&3&4&5
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&1&0\\
1&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&3&1&2\\
4&1&3&2\\
3&0&2&1\\
5&2&4&3
\end{bmatrix}\;.
$$

The first row of $A$ is the second row of $PAP^t$, and the first column of $A$ is the second column of $PAP^t$. The second row and second column of $A$ are the fourth row and column of $PAP^t$. The fourth row and column of $A$ are the first row and column of $PAP^t$. And the third row and column of $A$ are still the third row and column of $PAP^t$. In other words, both the rows and columns have been permuted by the permutation $(1,2,4)$ in cycle notation or

$$\pmatrix{1&2&3&4\\2&4&3&1}\tag{1}$$

in two-line notation. If $A$ is the adjacency matrix of a graph, $PAP^t$ is just the adjacency matrix of the same graph after the vertices have been renumbered according to the permutation $(1)$.

Comment: Hi @Brian M. Scott I am also working on this question. I am confused on how to proceed from here. I am trying to prove the if direction and so I have the isomorphism, but how do I build the permutation matrix out of that? I think my teacher actually wants us to construct the matrix.

Comment: @H_B: If you have the isomorphism, then you have the permutation of the vertices corresponding to $(1)$ in my answer. Apply that permutation to the rows of the $n\times n$ identity matrix (where $n$ is the number of vertices), and you’ll have the permutation matrix $P$.

Comment: I am sorry but I am still confused. Say I have drawn the house graph in two different ways $G_1$ and $G_2$, and I label the vertices $1,2,3,4,5$ and $a,b,c,d,e$ and I have the isomorphism $\{(1,d),(2,a),(3,c),(4,b),(5,e)\}$. How would I then do what you explained?

Comment: @H_B: Replace $a,b,c,d,e$ with $1,2,3,4,5$, respectively, so that you’re using the same set of labels for both graphs. Now your permutation analogous to $(1)$ is $$\pmatrix{1&2&3&4&5\\4&1&3&2&5}\;,$$ since $dacbe$ is now $41325$.

Comment: I see I see! The renaming was my hangup. Ok so now I understand how could I formally prove it? I am confused on how I should even get started.

Comment: @H_B: It depends on how much linear algebra you know. The key point, which you must either use or prove and then use, is that if $P$ is obtained from the isomorphism in the way that I described, then $PAP^t$ is just $A$ with its rows and columns permuted the same way. This means that $A$ and $PAP^t$ show the same adjacencies, but with the vertices listed in a different order.

Comment: I think if you could help me with the one direction, I could get the other direction after I am more familiar with how to work with these concepts(this is the first problem I was given in algebraic graph theory).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24328/discussion-between-h-b-and-brian-m-scott).