# Can we argue that two graphs are isomorphic iff their adjacency matrices have the same eigenvalues?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

### Context:

Inspired from the idea that we can show the isomorphism between two graphs by showing that the adjacency matrix of one of the graphs can be obtained by interchanging rows&columns (applying the corresponding operations at the same time) of the other's adjacency graph (when we give some order to their vertex set); I thought that since the adjacency matrix of any graph is symmetric, if we think it as a linear map (from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n $)for a second, we can argue that it is diagonalisable. Since the elementary row operations just correspond to multiplying the matrix from left and right by some permutation matrices, as stated in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331233/showing-two-graphs-isomorphic-using-their-adjacency-matrices); hence, two graphs should be isomorphic iff their adjacency matrices should have the "eigenvalues" when we consider their adjacency matrix as a linear map. Therefore, if formalise it;

> two graphs are isomorphic iff the adjacency matrix of two graphs
>   (with some ordered vertex set) have the same "eigenvalues".

For example, consider the graphs

[image]

and their adjacency matrices

[image]
[image]

As I have computed in [here](https://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diagonalize%20%7B%7B0%2C1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%20%7B1%2C0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%2C0%7D%7D) and [here](https://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diagonalize%20%7B%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%20%7B0%2C0%2C1%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C0%2C0%7D%7D)
both have the same (or some permutation of each other) diagonal form, so with this logic, they should be isomorphic (and actually are).

### Question:

Is this idea works in general. Can you spot where the argument might fail ? I mean after all, the adjacency matrix can't even have any real entries, and there is no geometric meaning of matrix multiplication for the adjacency matrix of a graph, so I couldn't prove this statement in formal way, but still ,for computational purposes, can we argue something about the validity of this method ?

Because as you can see, computationally diagonalising a matrix is not that of a problem (as long as the number of vertex is not large), and this method would give us a algorithm for determining whether two graphs are isomorphic or not.

**Addendum:**

As @Morgan pointed out in his comment, there are graphs which are not isomorphic but have the same set of eigenvalues, called cospectral graphs. However, I would like to know why the statement fails to be true.

Comment: No this is not true. Google "cospectral graphs"

Comment: @MorganRodgers Thanks for your comment. Ok, apparently the statement is not true in general; however, if there any explanation why the statements fails to be true ?

Comment: @MorganRodgers I have _already_ given my argument about why it should be true though it is not a rigorous argument, but still there is logic behind it, and I'm curios where is that logic fails.(i.e where the analogy fails.)

Comment: @MorganRodgers You are right. Thanks for the answer. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Multiplication of adjacency matrices does indeed have a topological meaning. For example, the entries of $A^k$ count paths of length $k$ between pairs of vertices.

Comment: @Simon Thanks for your comment Simon, I did not know that.

Comment: You're welcome ! I found these lecture notes by Dr. Rachel Quinlan very useful. You might, too: https://www.google.ro/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.maths.nuigalway.ie/~rquinlan/teaching/spectralgraphtheory.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwin_sjXgLfbAhUFjqQKHQ25BPYQFggkMAA&usg=AOvVaw3S4QsaJZWPzBOzwsAU8ZQQ