# Check whether two trees given by their adjacency matrices are isomorphic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms, trees

I know that there are several well-known algorithms for that but in this case, I suspect our professor expects something different. 
Two trees are given by their adjacency matrices. We need to check whether they are isomorphic. Just before this task, we were discussing tree encoding with ${0,1}$ so I assume there might be some approach using graph encoding.

Intuitively, it seems that isomorphic trees should have binary strings one of which if a permutation of the other. However, I have no idea whether this is correct.

Probably, there is a better way to use adjacency matrices for proving tree isomorphism.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It seems this would be the case if the matrices were permutations of each other. However, this does not use the fact that the graphs are trees, so I am not sure of this approach.

Comment: Ah, apparently I was on the right track: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331233/showing-two-graphs-isomorphic-using-their-adjacency-matrices